# Symfony. Doctrine. Выборка родительской сущности вместе со связанными

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine2, entity, relation

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос: есть некая сущность *А*, связана с сущностью *B* отношением многие ко многим:

```
class A {
/**
 * @var B[]
 *
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 protected $b
}

/**
 * return B[]
 */
public function getB(): array
{
   return $this->b
}
```

```
class B {
/**
 * @var A
 *
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="b", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $a;
```

Когда мне надо получить только модели сущности А, то недолго думая, делаю выборку:

```
$entitiesA = $repositoryOfEntityA->findBy([...]);
```

Когда я бегу по $entitiesA в цикле и обращаюсь в связанным сущностям:

```
foreach($entitiesA as $entityA) {
   $entityA->getB();
}
```

я каждый раз делаю запрос к БД, что и логично.

Как можно сформировать запрос, чтобы связанные записи В автоматом выбирались из БД, подгрудались в сущность А, и при вызове getB(), они возвращались из памяти?
Но надо оставить возможность получать и только сущности А при необходимости.

Comment: `fetch=eager/fetch=lazy`

Comment: @u_mulder эти правильна указываются в аннотации отношений, и получается каждый раз, выбирая сущности А, я будут из БД вытаскивать и сущности В. А мне надо сделать разделение -  в одном случае выбираю А и связанные сущности В, а в другом - только А

Comment: Можете указать в queryBuilder нужное вам поведение

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql